# Transitioning and applying different styles on multiple elements simultaneously

Tags: css

I have an anchor tag with 2 spans in it...

```
<a class="banner-logo" href="/search"><span id="banner-logo-hello">Hello</span><span id="banner-logo-world">World</span></a>
```

On hover of this anchor tag, I want to change the color of the text inside the spans, but I want them to each be a different color. Right now, I can only get one span to transition at a time. How can I get both transitions to occur simultaneously regardless of which span inside of the anchor tag is hovered on?

```
#banner-logo-hello:hover,
#banner-logo-hello:active,
#banner-logo-hello:focus {
  color: red;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#banner-logo-world:hover,
#banner-logo-world:active,
#banner-logo-world:focus {
  color: yellow;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: Please share your code you have so far as a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Target `a:hover #span-id-name {}` for both of the spans

```css
a:hover #banner-logo-hello {
  color: red;
}

a:hover #banner-logo-world {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a class="banner-logo" href="/search"><span id="banner-logo-hello">Hello</span><span id="banner-logo-world">World</span></a>
```

You can also target via `:nth-child`, or it's variations like `:first-child` or `:last-child` or `:nth-of-type`

```css
a:hover span:last-child {
  color: red;
}

a:hover span:first-child {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a class="banner-logo" href="/search"><span id="banner-logo-hello">Hello</span><span id="banner-logo-world">World</span></a>
```

Comment: Ah yes! I was targeting the elements incorrectly. Hindsight... ugh. Thank you!

Comment: @JeffMiller no problem!